# Should I separate my preferences table?

Tags: mysql, optimization, php

I have a hobby site where users can find other hobbyists of similar interest.  Each user can set a series of preferences that get saved into `user_prefs`.  Right now there are 4 types of preferences, an example of those are `genre`.  Any user can select a like/dislike for a subject under `genre` like 'Science Fiction'. That subject under genre is then saved as a `1` or `0` in the `user_prefs` table.

Right now all 4 types of preferences are being saved in the `user_prefs` table.  But with only a few hundred users as my hobby site is getting started, thats over 8,000 rows.  A single user could have 135 possible rows right now.  Am I right in thinking that with 10k users at 135 rows, 1.35 million rows might be a bit silly for fast page load?

The query that looks at `user_prefs` might be run 4 to 100 times or more on a page.  Let me explain why.

The query runs inside a radial distance loop that uses postal codes to display users within a maximum distance.  So only users within that distance will be found, the hard maximum is 90 miles although the user can select a much smaller range.

When a user searches a distance, a query runs this statement:

```
foreach ($central_location->getZipsInRange($zip_link,$minimum, $radius) as $miles => $zip) {
```

For every single postal code in radius, there is another query that checks if any user's match that postal code.  If there are users in that particular postal code, it lists them.  Then each single user's preferences are looked at 4 times inside the postal code loop.

Each of those 4 queries is this statement with only `genre` changed to another keyword:

```
SELECT user_list.user_name, user_list.first_name, game_genre.gamer_genre
    FROM user_list
    JOIN users_prefs ON user_list.user_index = users_prefs.user_id
    JOIN game_genre ON users_prefs.prefs_index = game_genre.genre_index
    WHERE users_prefs.prefs_type = 'genre'           
    AND users_prefs.declared_prefs = 1
    AND user_list.user_name = '$user_name'  
    ORDER BY game_genre.gamer_genre ASC
```

So should I further denormalize the 4 types of preferences into different tables and keep the 4 statements?

Or should I leave the table together, assume that a query against a few million rows won't slow things down but combine the preferences query into a single statement?

I was pondering making the 4 statements into 1 single statement then using PHP to separate it out but the idea of a million rows or more feels pretty slow to me.

Either way for me, this has been a learning experience.  The site is using PHP v5.4.29 and the MYSQL clone Percona v5.5.37-35.1.  My host is HostGator on the baby hatchling plan, so I don't have a server power.

I'd be interested in not only suggestions about my 2 main questions but also other ideas.  Keep in mind my skill level is that of "adventurous novice."  Looking forward to some great suggestions.

Comment: Why on earth would anyone want to have a list of 10,000 users from all over the plant visible at startup? I want to see the 20 or 40 *closest* users to my current location (or some known location to which I am expecting to travel), filtered by preference. Stop worrying about size of your database at this point; with modern equipment it is irrelevant until you are being looked at by FACEBOOK as s serious rival. And Yes, keep your preferences in one single table. You will only give your self heartache by splitting it up.

Comment: Nobody would.  I updated the question so you'll see it doesn't.  But I have waited a long long time for some million row queries.  Planning ahead is smart, is it not?